# TFS Performance Issue

Tags: tfs

Since we installed most recent Windows Update patches, TFS performance has been very slow. The w3wp process is much higher than it used to be. We see the following messages in the Application Event Viewer every minute or so but not sure why this is happening.

Event 9011

The application is beginning to shutdown.The application is being shutdown for the following reason: ConfigurationChange

Application Domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/tfs-2-130753972266714252

Event 9002

The application is being shutdown for the following reason: ConfigurationChange

Application Domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/tfs-2-130753972266714252

Event 9001

Application Request Processing Started

Server Version = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

Service Account = ADSDELTEKCOM\TFSSERVICE

Machine Name = ASHWSP10VS

Product ID = 06205-004-0470003-02392

License Edition = PID_RANGE_MSDN

Application Domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/tfs-3-130753972399983644

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something has been broken. If you are not on TFS 2013 Update 4 then you should update.

If you have Update 4 then you may want to I configure the app tier and reconfigure it. If someone has changed the settings in IIS outside of the admin console then this will reset then.